# R and H2O: MySQL JDBC Connection Error

Tags: mysql, r, h2o

I am attempting to use the h2o package in R to query a MySQL database and store the results directly in an h2o instance I have running on my local machine.

Provided below is all of my code and errors received, I would very much appreciate a new set of eyes to help me troubleshoot - thanks!

Via Windows Command Prompt:

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\h2o-3.8.2.6\h2o.jar;C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-5.1.39\mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar" water.H2OApp
```

Which returns:

```
05-31 12:20:41.601 127.0.0.1:54321       5280   main      INFO: HDFS subsystem successfully initialized
05-31 12:20:41.602 127.0.0.1:54321       5280   main      INFO: S3 subsystem successfully initialized
05-31 12:20:41.604 127.0.0.1:54321       5280   main      INFO: Flow dir: 'C:/Users/ekorne201/h2oflows'
05-31 12:20:41.925 127.0.0.1:54321       5280   main      INFO: Cloud of size 1 formed [/127.0.0.1:54321]
05-31 12:20:41.931 127.0.0.1:54321       5280   main      INFO: Registered 0 extensions in: 531mS
05-31 12:20:42.525 127.0.0.1:54321       5280   main      INFO: Registered: 124 REST APIs in: 553mS
05-31 12:20:42.995 127.0.0.1:54321       5280   main      INFO: Registered: 193 schemas in: 468mS
05-31 12:20:42.995 127.0.0.1:54321       5280   main      INFO:
05-31 12:20:42.996 127.0.0.1:54321       5280   main      INFO: Open H2O Flow in your web browser: http://127.0.0.1:54321/
05-31 12:20:42.998 127.0.0.1:54321       5280   main      INFO:
```

Then, via R I run the following
(db/server details masked):

```
#packages
require(h2o)

ip          <-      '127.0.0.1'
port        <-      54321
h2o.init(ip = ip, port = port)

#db details
dbip        <-      'XX.XX.XX.XX'
dbport      <-      'XXXX'
dblogin     <-      'login'
dbpass      <-      'password'

#test connection
test <- h2o.import_sql_select(
connection_url = paste("jdbc:mysql://", dbip, ":", dbport, "/myDB?useSSL=false", sep = ''),
select_query = 'select * from myTable limit 1000',
username = dblogin,
password = dbpass)
```

which returns the following errors:

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 500 Server Error (url = http://127.0.0.1:54321/99/ImportSQLTable)

java.lang.RuntimeException
[1] "java.lang.RuntimeException: SQLException: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.\nFailed to connect and read from SQL database with connection_url: jdbc:mysql://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/assumption_matrix?useSSL=false"
[2] "    water.jdbc.SQLManager.importSqlTable(SQLManager.java:135)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[3] "    water.api.ImportSQLTableHandler.importSQLTable(ImportSQLTableHandler.java:15)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[4] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[5] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[6] "    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[7] "    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[8] "    water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:62)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[9] "    water.api.RequestServer.handle(RequestServer.java:655)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[10] "    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:596)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[11] "    water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doGeneric(JettyHTTPD.java:745)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[12] "    water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doPost(JettyHTTPD.java:681)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[13] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[14] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[15] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[16] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[17] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[18] "    org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[19] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[20] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[21] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[22] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[23] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[24] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[25] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[26] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[27] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[28] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[29] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[30] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[31] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[32] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[33] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[34] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[35] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[36] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[37] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[38] "    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

SQLException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Failed to connect and read from SQL database with connection_url: jdbc:mysql://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/myDB?useSSL=false
```

I'm stumped and would appreciate any help.  I am able to connect to this server via ODBC without trouble.  Thanks!

Comment: this is hardly h2o problem, or, the least, not yet an h2o problem, before you troubleshoot the MySQL JDBC connectivity in your environment. I refer you to couple questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2983248/59470 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/6865538/59470